# Django haystack highlighting multiple models and fields as one item

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack (whoosh backend), and I have a setup where I want to search multiple fields in multiple models, and preferably be able to add fields to the index fairly easily. I also want to use highlighting.

My issue is that as far as I can tell I have to use the highlight template tags on each field I wish to highlight. I'm using it like this:

```
{% highlight result.object.content with query %}
{% highlight result.object.other_field with query %}
```

I haven't even got to multiple models yet, this method has some issues even with just multiple fields in the same model. Firstly, I'd have to write this for every field of every model. Not all models have a content field, some of the models I'm indexing have different fields I'd wish to highlight. Also, the tag spams out the field even if there are no matches within that field, as long as there is a match somewhere in the indexed fields of the model. This is not desirable.

What I want is to be able to collate all of these fields into one place (like how the search index template works) and then highlight just that. Is this possible?

In the [template tag docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags.html) the tag is used like this: `{% highlight result.summary with query %}`. I had assumed this might do something like what I'm wanting, but the [SearchResult API docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchresult_api.html) do not mention it, and attempting this line just gives me a `None` object back.

Comment: Were you ever able to get a solution for this? Also facing the same problem.

Comment: I don't remember, but probably not. I haven't used haystack in a long time. I would probably suggest using postgres full text search or elasticsearch depending on what you need.